# Getting the ID of @react-native-community/datetimepicker

Tags: react-native

I'm using multiple `@react-native-community/datetimepicker`'s in my component and they both call the same function when the user picks a date.

How do I get the ID or name of the `datetimepicker` the user has used? I checked but was not able to find the ID or name property. This is what the date picker looks like:

```
<DateTimePicker
   testID="myDate1"
   value={myDateValue}
   mode="date"
   display="default"
   onChange={this.onCalendarDateChange} />
```

And this is the function that gets called when the user selects a date:

```
onCalendarDateChange(event, selectedDate) {

   const id = event.???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with this package a while, I realized, the idea is to have a single `datetimepicker` in a form which is why there's no way to retrieve the ID of the picker.

The simple solution I came up with, which works nicely, is to capture the name of the form field for which the `datetimepicker` is collecting data when I make it visible.

In my case, I have two form fields for which I needed a `datetimepicker` i.e. `startDate` and `endDate` and initially I was trying to use two separate `datetimepicker`'s in my form. This is completely unnecessary.

I now use a single `datetimepicker` and when the user clicks the calendar icon to show the `datetimepicker`, I set the name of the form field i.e. `startDate` or `endDate` in the `state`. Once the user selects a date, the `onCalendarDateChange()` gets called and I simply read from the `state` whether it's `startDate` or `endDate` field that invoked the `datetimepicker`.

So anyone who needs a `datetimepicker` for multiple form fields can simply use a single `datetimepicker` to get the job done using my or a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Based on its the [document](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/blob/master/src/datetimepicker.android.js) event is an object with two keys

```
 const event: AndroidEvent = {
        type: 'set',
        nativeEvent: {},
      };
```

it does not return any ID to catch it

Comment: So, I have to use two separate but almost identical functions to determine which datetimepicker is returning the value in case I implement two datetimepickers in a component? For three datetimepickers, have three functions? This seems counter to any basic programming principles.

Comment: With that said, looks like you’re right about not being able to retrieve the ID or name of datetimepicker according to this: https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/259#issuecomment-693239446

Comment: Hard to believe that we’re unable to identify where the value comes from in such a popular solution.